# rowFill a specific row?

Tags: api, gantt-chart, anychart

I am trying to fill the background color of every 2 rows.

[EveryOther2Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgKwO.png)

I'm currently using a complex linear-gradient to achieve this, but there are some rows that look incorrect.

[ColorArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONodM.png)

Is it possible to target specific rows with rowFill to set a background color?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the AnyGantt v8.10.0 doesn't support this possibility. All the available coloring options are described in [the documentation article](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Timeline/Appearance).
We will take into account this requirement for future updates.